# Obtain Browser Downloaded Files with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I'm currently using Capybara / Poltergeist with PhantomJS.  Is there any way to get files that were downloaded by the 'browser' using this setup (e.g. that would be obtained after navigating to a URI)?

Either the URI of the file or the actual file itself would be great.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of time poltergeist download and what do you wanna test for the file?

Comment: Poltergeist is trying to download a CSV file; I'll want to test the actual content to make sure it's as expected.

Comment: Thanks. How about this article http://it.fyber.com/blog/2012/11/29/capybara-poltergeist-and-csv-downloads/

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting; thanks!  I'll look into using that fix.

Answer (score -1):

One of solution is this - http://it.fyber.com/blog/2012/11/29/capybara-poltergeist-and-csv-downloads/

---

Other is to use CSV Ruby library.

Download CSV File is here.

```
id,name,note
1,name1,note1
2,name2,note2
3,name3,note3
```

And, your spec file

```
require 'csv'

feature "Products", :type => :feature do
  describe "Download CSV" do
    # ... click csv download button by Capybara

    rows = CSV.parse(page.body, :row_sep => "\r\n", :force_quotes => true)
    # [["id", "name", "note"], ["1", "name1", "note1"], ["2", "name2", "note2"], ["3", "name3", "note3"]]

    # assert csv header
    header = rows[0]
    expect(header).to eq ["id", "name", "note"]

    # assert csv rows
    # it's better to define expected csv rows and use `each` method
    expect(rows[1]).to eq ["1", "name1", "note1"]
    expect(rows[2]).to eq ["2", "name2", "note2"]
    expect(rows[3])>to eq ["3", "name3", "note3"]
  end
end
```

Comment: The CSV Ruby library doesn't help - because page.body will not contain the CSV if you click the download button.

Comment: @SamStephens I tried `CSV.parse(page.body)` on feature spec. I did it. Please confirm.

Comment: page.body won't contain the CSV unless you've done something else as well. A CSV should normally be served with a text/csv content type, which causes Poltergeist to download it rather than treat it as a page. That's the behavior that the fyber.com article you link to is supposed to work around. CSV.parse is useful once you have access to the contents of the CSV file, but the question isn't about CSV parsing - it's about accessing the contents of the file.

Comment: I recently had a simliar variation of this problem, which I ended up solving by swapping to the webkit driver.